# Redux_Saga. How to past the function as an argument to the nested Generator?

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

So, I want to push some function `setupSocket` as the argument to execution inside the nested Generator `createSaga`, but now I cannot understand how can I make it?

Inside the parent Generator `mySaga` the `setupSocket` displayed normally, but inside the `createSaga` nope...

```
import { takeEvery, put, call, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'; 
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { addMessage, addUser } from '../actions'
import * as constants from '../constants'

function* createSaga(action, setupSocket) {
    try {
        console.log(setupSocket); // not good
        yield put(addMessage(action.message, action.author, action.photo));
        yield put(addUser(action.author, action.photo));
    } catch (e) { 
        console.log(e) 
    }
};

function* mySaga(setupSocket) {
    console.log(setupSocket); // all good
    yield takeEvery(constants.ADD_DATA, createSaga);
};

export default mySaga;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass additional arguments to `takeEvery` that will be passed down to the saga.

```
function* createSaga(setupSocket, action) {
    console.log(setupSocket); // should now be good
    ...
};

function* mySaga(setupSocket) {
    yield takeEvery(constants.ADD_DATA, createSaga, setupSocket);
};
```

If you pass down some arguments, `action` will be always the last one so I had to swap `action` and `setupSaga` order in the `createSaga` saga arguments.

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args

Comment: No effect.. In you case the `setupSocket` takes role of `action` and display all values inside it. As for `action` - in this case it's undefined

Comment: Did you pass `setupSocket` as the third argument of your `takeEvery` ?

Comment: @MaxWolfen you must be just missing something, see working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zzm67lw5l (there is console panel you need to open at the bottom)